# Executar tarefa sincronizada com o relógio

Tags: android

Eu gostaria de executar uma tarefa sincronizada com o relógio do android.

> Por exemplo:
>   no segundo 0, depois no segundo 10, 20, 30, 40 e 50.
>   Não quero executar a cada 10 segundos, quero executar nestes segundos exatos.

Existe uma maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para realizar isso você pode utilizar a classe `AlarmManager` e o método `setRepeating`, porém na documentação desse método é dito que é mais fácil e eficiente a utilização de `Handler`s.

Na classe `Handler` você agenda `Runnable`s para serem executados no futuro e também em um determinado tempo. O método `Handler#postAtTime` recebe um `Runnable` e um tempo baseado no tempo de execução do Android, por exemplo, para agendar a cada 10 segundos, faça:

```
final AtomicLong tick = new AtomicLong(SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
        + 10000L); // timestamp de 10 segundos no futuro

mHandler = new Handler(); // sem acesso a UI Thread
// mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()); // handler ligado a UI Thread
                                                   // ou seja, pode modificar a UI
mHandler.postAtTime(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // reagendar-se daqui a 10 segundos
        mHandler.postAtTime(this, tick.addAndGet(10000L));

        // TODO: realizar tarefa
    }
}, tick.get());
```

Só falta você bolar um mecanismo para pegar a hora exata e depois ir incrementando o `tick`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Alguns links úteis:

- [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)
- [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)
- [AlarmManager#setRepeating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))
- [SystemClock](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html)
- [Comunicando com a UI Thread](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)

Comment: Rubem muito obrigado mesmo, vou seguir tuas dicas e assim que conseguir posto aqui novamente...

Comment: Fiz assim e ficou perfeito cara, mais uma vez obrigado: if ( started == false ) {
      int segundos = Util.segundoAtual();
      switch(segundos) {
      case 0: case 10: case 20: case 30: case 40: case 50:
       started = true;
       iniciaTimerNaHora();
       break;
      }
     }

Comment: Valeu! Se preferir, aceita a reposta.